# How to get the list of the unsupported packages mentioned during the OS upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

While running `sudo do-release-upgrade`, I got a message saying:

> 16 installed packages are no longer supported by Canonical. You can still get support from the community.

I know I probably shouldn't be worried, but how can I get a list of those packages before starting the upgrade?

The following is the complete output of `do-release-upgrade` before choosing continue: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12990830/

For better convenience, this is the most important part of it:

```
Calculating the changes

Do you want to start the upgrade? 


16 installed packages are no longer supported by Canonical. You can 
still get support from the community. 

61 packages are going to be removed. 204 new packages are going to be 
installed. 1617 packages are going to be upgraded. 

You have to download a total of 1,220 M. This download will take 
about 55 minutes with your connection. 

Installing the upgrade can take several hours. Once the download has 
finished, the process cannot be canceled. 

 Continue [yN]  Details [d]
```

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I'm upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10, does the version matter though?

Comment: @Dan yes it does.

Comment: During the upgrade process you should see a list of the unsupported packages.

Comment: @A.B. I edited into the question the output of `do-release-upgrade` just before I choose continue.

Comment: I would say, use `d` for details.

Comment: I guess `d` will show those, as [demoted packages used to be shown by `do-release-upgrade` in previous Ubuntu versions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1474148&p=9251847#post9251847).

Comment: @A.B. Wow, i swear i read that a billion times (exaggerating just a bit). I did not notice that `Details` at all, my mind just doesn't want to read it. Excuse my dumbness. Either way, it would be nice if there is a way to get the list after we select `N`. If you add that as an answer,  so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The first option: Press <kbd>D</kbd> to see the details after starting `sudo do-release-upgrade` as you can see it in the output of the command in your question.
- The second option: Use `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`

  ```
  awk -F\' '/demoted/ {gsub(/ /,"\n",$2); print $2}' /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log
  ```

  to see something like this

  ```
  dvipng
  gir1.2-vte-2.90
  gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
  libart2.0-cil
  libgconf2-4
  libgconf2.0-cil
  libgnome-vfs2.0-cil
  libgnome2.24-cil
  libvte-2.90-9
  monodoc-manual
  obex-data-server
  python-commandnotfound
  rhythmbox-mozilla
  ```
- The third option: You can see a list of the installed community packages with this command

  ```
  aptitude search '~i ~suniverse' -F "%p"
  ```

  to see something like this

  ```
  adwaitaicon-theme-full
  aglfn
  aha                                                                           
  android-tools-adb                                                                  
  android-tools-fastboot
  anjuta
  anjuta-common
  apt-file
  […snip…]
  ```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the last one would be more accurate after the upgrade is complete, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4):

When you drop out of the do-release-upgrade script, whether you select `N` or `y`, the log will be saved in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`.

Getting the list of unsupported packages is a matter of running the following command:

```
grep 'demoted' /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log
```

you would get an output similar to:

```
2015-10-28 18:14:01,540 DEBUG demoted: 'gir1.2-vte-2.90 gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps libpocketsphinx1 libsphinxbase1 libunityvoice1 libvte-2.90-9 libvte-2.90-common obex-data-server python-commandnotfound rhythmbox-mozilla sphinx-voxforge-hmm-en sphinx-voxforge-lm-en ubuntu-wallpapers-vivid unity-voice-service'
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the easiest and most direct way to do this is with this command (as of Ubuntu 20.04):

```
ubuntu-security-status --unavailable
```

This will give you an output like this:

```
1734 packages installed, of which:
  13 packages are no longer available for download
dvipng gir1.2-vte-2.90 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic libart2.0-cil 
 libgconf2-4 libgconf2.0-cil libgnome-vfs2.0-cil libgnome2.24-cil 
 libvte-2.90-9 monodoc-manual obex-data-server python-commandnotfound 
 rhythmbox-mozilla

Packages that are not available for download may be left over from a
previous release of Ubuntu, may have been installed directly from a
.deb file, or are from a source which has been disabled.

Run 'apt-cache show dvipng' to learn more about that package.
```

Comment: I feel this can be different from the original question (maybe a package has been removed from the new version, but it is still available in the repositories). But this is very interesting nonetheless!