# How to find which package is "no longer supported"?

Tags: package-management, 22.04

I finally upgraded my daily driver from 21.10 to 22.04.1 yesterday, and in the process I got the notification that 1 installed package is no longer supported by Canonical, still supported by the community.

Sorry to ask a stupid question, but how do I find out which package this is, so I don't miss getting updates?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/691150/15811

Comment: Canonical decided to switch Mozilla Firefox is in 22.04 to a snap-package instead of a .deb-package. So I think it is that package.

Comment: Such changes happen regularly with new releases of Ubuntu --nothing special going on-- and such changes wouldn't cause you to "*miss getting updates*." Also "*supported by the community*" is still *support*!

Comment: I've added an answer to the above thread, which I believe is the easiest way to get this information on Ubuntu 20.04 and later.